How to cache nextjs pages using cloudflare for non logged in users only using cookie set or not
is it possible serve cache pages from cloudflare if a cookie is set or not? I am trying to serve pages from cache if user is not logged in. We add a cookie if not logged in and another cookie if logged in. Problem is, after caching once, it always serve from the cache and it doesn't respect other request.
